# How to call inner functions from one JavaScript file to another JavaScript file in WebStorm? (except using module.exports)

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I tried using module.exports as well but it's not detecting module.exports in my WebStorm. So, how to enable module.exports in WebStorm?
Another thing is I am trying to get function from another js file. Something like we do inheritance in Java I am expecting here in JavaScript.
below is my code:-
locate.js

/**
 *
 */

```
var locate = function()
{

 var a = 10;

 function inner(_block)`
{
console.log( "Hello", _block+" "+a )`;
}
locate.inner = inner;
}

locate();
locate.inner( "World" );
//console.log(locate);
module.export = locate;
```

delocate.js

```
let a;
a = require('./locate.js');
console.log(a);
a.inner("Universe");` //inner is not visible gives error
```

> ```
> a.inner("Universe");
>   ^
> ```
>
> TypeError: a.inner is not a function

Expected output should be HelloUniverse10

Comment: apart from possible other issues, "module.export**s**"

Comment: is this for nodejs app ??

Comment: yes this on Nodejs....module.exports not showing at all

Comment: Why are you using back quote (`\``) in the middle of your code?! It's `module.exports` indeed.

Comment: `  was by mistake

Comment: Basically want to access function from file A(locate.js) in fileB(delocate.js). Take it locate.js as base class and delocate.js as derived one. How can i get call functions inner as well as global from locate.js to delocate.js?

Answer (score 1):

it can be

```
var locate = function() {

  var a      = 10;
  var locate = {}

  function inner(_block) {
    console.log('Hello',
      _block + ' ' + a);
  }

  locate.inner = inner;
  return locate;
}


module.exports = locate;
```

and

```
const a = require('./locate')();
console.log(a);
a.inner("Universe");
```

Note that this has absolutely nothing to do with Webstorm; your code is run with Node.js, so it's all about javascript and commonJS modules syntax

Comment: seems its working...any other solution related to extend class or something....trying to avoid using module.exports

Comment: if you aren't using modules/node.js, and just include all your files in your HTML page via `<script>` tags, functions defined in one file shoulf be available in another without exports